# JIRA : Issue status count for the past x (i.e 30 ) days

Tags: mysql, sql, jira

With below Query I able to see the count(no) of issues for all issueType in JIRA for a given date .

ie.

```
  SELECT count(*), STEP.STEP_ID
  FROM (SELECT STEP_ID, ENTRY_ID
  FROM OS_CURRENTSTEP
  WHERE OS_CURRENTSTEP.START_DATE < '<your date>'
  UNION SELECT STEP_ID, ENTRY_ID
  FROM OS_HISTORYSTEP
  WHERE OS_HISTORYSTEP.START_DATE < '<your date>'
  AND OS_HISTORYSTEP.FINISH_DATE > '<your date>' ) As STEP,
  (SELECT changeitem.OLDVALUE AS VAL, changegroup.ISSUEID AS ISSID
  FROM changegroup, changeitem
  WHERE changeitem.FIELD = 'Workflow'
  AND changeitem.GROUPID = changegroup.ID
  UNION SELECT jiraissue.WORKFLOW_ID AS VAL, jiraissue.id as ISSID
  FROM jiraissue) As VALID,
  jiraissue as JI
  WHERE STEP.ENTRY_ID = VALID.VAL
  AND VALID.ISSID = JI.id
 AND JI.project = <proj_id>
  Group By STEP.STEP_ID;
```

the result is

```
Status   Count
open       12
closed      13
.....     ....
```

What I'd like to achieve is something like this actually ..where the total count for status open and closed for each day .

```
Date        COUNT(Open)      COUNT(Closed)
12-1-2012     12                 1
13-1-2012      14                5
```

Comment: I wrote the JIRA Timecharts plugin to do this, but it's quite fiddly to use.

Comment: Thanks Mdoar ,Is there any link I can refer to ? or probably share the query ?

Comment: ohh got it from this link https://studio.plugins.atlassian.com/wiki/display/TMCT/JIRA+Timecharts+Plugin     ..by any chance I able to know the query ?Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The general strategy would be this:

Select from a table of all the days in a month

LEFT OUTER JOIN your table that gets counts for each day

(left outer join being necessary in case there were no entries for that day, you'd want it to show a zero value).

So I think this is roughly what you need (not complete and date-function syntax is probably wrong for your db, but it will get you closer):

```
SELECT aDate
, COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN IssueStatus = 'whateverMeansOpen' THEN 1 END,0)) OpenCount
, COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN IssueStatus = 'whateverMeansClosed' THEN 1 END,0)) ClosedCount
FROM
(
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, I, @START_DATE)  aDate
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT number AS I FROM [SomeTableWithAtLeast31Rows]
        where number between 1 and 31
    ) Numbers
    WHERE DATEADD(DAY, I, @START_DATE) < @END_DATE
) DateTimesInInterval 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    Put your query here. It needs to output two columns, DateTimeOfIssue and IssueStatus
) yourHugeQuery ON yourHugeQuery.DateTimeOfIssue BETWEEN aDate and DATEADD(DAY, 1, aDate)
GROUP BY aDate
ORDER BY aDate
```